# Why is all of the text on my window blank?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Sorry for asking such a basic question, but I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to display a status window that just says "Uninstalling prior versions" while the program runs so the user has some idea what's going on. So I created a C# form, added a label and do a window.show(). Here's what the form looks like in design mode:

[image]

And yet here's what displays:

[image]

I added a second label and a button to make sure that the text of my label wasn't some odd color or something that was causing the problem and they don't appear either.

What's going on here? This should be so simple. I've done this hundreds of times and never seen this behavior.

Comment: Sounds like the app is running some long running process on the main thread and that is blocking the screen refresh of this window. I would suggest that your other logic start using some async/await logic to handle that long running process. This will allow the UI thread to not be blocked.

Comment: You can call Refresh() before starting the long-running work.

Comment: You're blocking  the UI thread, with a close loop, maybe. Add `.Refresh()` after `.Show()`. The user won't be able to interact with the Form, but it looks like there isn't much to interact with anyway. Unless that Button is meant to allow to cancel the operation...

Comment: I guess you are changing the text in the label during a loop ? In that case, do `LabelProgress.Update()` just after `LabelProgress.Text = "blablabla"`.

Answer (score 1):

[TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227980/why-is-all-of-the-text-on-my-window-blank/55244654#comment97191303_55227980):

> You can call Refresh() before starting the long-running work.

Refresh() was just what I needed!